How to make manure/compost out of chicken poo?
What are different things I can do?
Like, do I have to mix it in with cow poo or straw and then let it compost?
Do I add earthworms? Or do I just let it age and then use?
Or use as it is fresh?
Does it burn the plants if used fresh?

I use it fresh, but take into account that it is a strong fertilizer, so not to near roots and not too much. No need to compost, but you can do it to mix it (so less strong).
